# how create simple(servelet) java ee project in eclipse and tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, web-applications, tomcat, servlets

I'm open to

> eclipse --> new --> dynamic web
>   project --> in target runtime --> new
>   Apache Tomcat v6.0 and establish mark
>   Create a new local server --> next
>   Browse establish way
>   C:\dev\apache-tomcat-6.0.29-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-6.0.29
>   --> finish --> in new dynamic project finish

in Java Resources : src new class

```
java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
public class f extends HttpServlet 
{
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        resp.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
        PrintWriter pw = resp.getWriter();
        pw.println("<H1>Hello, world! или Привет мир</H1>");
    }
}
```

> -->server start in save resources s.java been modified. Save changes? I'm yes. --> Run servlet/s --> result 
>   HTTP Status 404 - /s/servlet/s

---

type Status report

message /s/servlet/s

description The requested resource (/s/servlet/s) is not available.

---

Apache Tomcat/6.0.14

How and when I'm error? 
How need the create right?

I'm sorry, bad English. explain most clear and distinctly

Comment: did eclipse not complain that **class f** has to be saved in a file called *f.java* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the `web.xml` deployment descriptor?
There you have to define your servlet mapping, or otherwise the servlet container won't have notice of the servlet.

Example:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

   <!-- Servlet definition -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>s</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>your.package.path.s</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

   <!-- servlet mapping -->
   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>s</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/myServlet</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
<web-app>
```

And now, you can access it with your mapped path ("`/<contextPath>/myServlet`") or with the default invoker ("`/<contextPath>/servlet/s`").

Comment: Be careful, the web.xml root declaration in this example would force Tomcat 6.0 (supports Servlet 2.5) to run like Tomcat 5.0 (Servlet 2.3 modus) and thus you won't be able to utilitze the new Servlet 2.4/2.5 classes/methods. Prefer to declare the web.xml to max servlet version as supported by servletcontainer.